# How to change the values in several columns of a data frame, when they have the same value in another specific column?

Tags: r

So I have a data frame such as this, with occurrences of several species, from three different countries:

```
 Species           |  Country_A | Country_B  | Country_C   
-----------------------------------------------------
Tilapia guineensis |   yes      |   no       |  no
Tilapia guineensis |   no       |   yes      |  no
Tilapia zillii     |   no       |   no       |  yes
Tilapia zillii     |   no       |   no       |  no
Eutrigla gurnardus |   no       |   yes      |  no
Eutrigla gurnardus |   yes      |   no       |  no 
Sprattus sprattus  |   yes      |   no       |  no 
Sprattus sprattus  |   yes      |   no       |  no
Sprattus sprattus  |   no       |   yes      |  no
Aetobatus narinari |   no       |   no       |  yes
Aetobatus narinari |   yes      |   no       |  no
Aetobatus narinari |   yes      |   no       |  no 
Aetobatus narinari |   yes      |   no       |  no
```

I wanted to basically change the columns of the countries and change to "yes" if any occurence of that species has "yes" in that country in other rows. I'm sorry if I'm being confusing.
What I wanted to do is something like this:

```
 Species           |  Country_A | Country_B  | Country_C   
-----------------------------------------------------
Tilapia guineensis |   yes      |   yes      |  no
Tilapia zillii     |   no       |   no       |  yes
Eutrigla gurnardus |   yes      |   yes      |  no
Sprattus sprattus  |   yes      |   yes      |  no 
Aetobatus narinari |   yes      |   no       |  yes
```

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try reshaping data, then keep the desired values, manage duplicated rows and reshape to wide:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  filter(value!='no') %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(name)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value,values_fill='no')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   Species [5]
  Species            Country_A Country_B Country_C
  <chr>              <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Tilapia guineensis yes       yes       no       
2 Tilapia zillii     no        no        yes      
3 Eutrigla gurnardus yes       yes       no       
4 Sprattus sprattus  yes       yes       no       
5 Aetobatus narinari yes       no        yes
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Species = c("Tilapia guineensis", "Tilapia guineensis", 
"Tilapia zillii", "Tilapia zillii", "Eutrigla gurnardus", "Eutrigla gurnardus", 
"Sprattus sprattus", "Sprattus sprattus", "Sprattus sprattus", 
"Aetobatus narinari", "Aetobatus narinari", "Aetobatus narinari", 
"Aetobatus narinari"), Country_A = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes"), 
    Country_B = c("no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", 
    "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"), Country_C = c("no", 
    "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", 
    "no", "no")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily with a group by operation in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(any(. == 'yes')) 'yes'
           else 'no'), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  Species            Country_A Country_B Country_C
#  <chr>              <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#1 Aetobatus narinari yes       no        yes      
#2 Eutrigla gurnardus yes       yes       no       
#3 Sprattus sprattus  yes       yes       no       
#4 Tilapia guineensis yes       yes       no       
#5 Tilapia zillii     no        no        yes
```